# Defining where Paperclip stores the attachment locally when running Spec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using AmazonS3 to store Paperclip attachments on all non-`test` environments.

For `test` specifically I use a local path/url setup to avoid interacting with S3 remotely

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] =
  ":rails_root/public/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename"

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] =
  "/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename"
```

I define my attachment as follows in the model

```
has_attached_file :source_file, use_timestamp: false
```

In my Production code I **need** to access the file using `Model.source_file.url` because `.url` returns the remote fully qualified Amazon S3 path to the file. This generally works fine for non-`test` environments.

However on my `test` environment I can't use `.url` because Paperclip creates and stores the file under the path defined by `:path` above. So I need to use `.path`. If I use `.url` I get the error -

```
Errno::ENOENT:
  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /system/test/imports/source_files/000/000/030/sample.txt
```

which makes sense because paperclip didn't store the file there...

How do I get paperclip on my `test` environment to store/create my file under the `:url` path so I can use `.url` correctly?

**Edit**: If it helps, in `test` I create the attachment from a locally stored fixture file

```
factory :import do
  source_file { File.new(Rails.root + "spec/fixtures/files/sample.tsv") }
end
```

**Edit2**: Setting `:path` and `:url` to be the same path in the initializer might seem like a quick fix, but I'm working on a larger app with several contributors, so I don't the have the luxury to do that or break any one else's specs. Plus it looks like Thoughtbot themselves recommend this setup, so there should be a "proper" way to get it working as is.

Thanks!

Comment: I think problems like this are why the majority of the ruby community left Paperclip behind for less monolithic tools like Carrierwave years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [s3proxy](https://github.com/andrewgaul/s3proxy) in your test environment to simulate S3 instead of directly have paperclip write to local files?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I hadn't heard of that. However that doesn't solve the core issue - paperclip is designed to store locally to bypass the need for any s3 mocking library. Would love to get it working without having to resort to another library/gem